# Inserted picture not visible in excel (only sizing borders)

Tags: excel, vba, image

I've found/written a macro in excel which allows me to insert a picture in a cell so that excel automatically fits the picture to the size of the cell.

```
Sub InsertAndSizePhoto()
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim oShape As Shape
    If TypeName(ActiveSheet) <> "Worksheet" Then Exit Sub
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim folderPath As String

    folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Images (*.gif;*.jpg;*.png), *.gif;*.jpg;*.png", _
        FilterIndex:=1, _
        Title:="Insert Picture", _
        ButtonText:="Insert", _
        MultiSelect:=False)
    If sFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

    With ActiveCell.MergeArea
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
            Filename:=sFileName, _
            LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
            SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
            Left:=.Left, _
            Top:=.Top, _
            Width:=.Width, _
            Height:=.Height
    End With
End Sub
```

Sometimes multiples pictures are inserted and fitted but they are not visible. Only the sizing window/border becomes visible when I click on the picture. They are also not visible in print preview. When I print the document in PDF of on paper they are visible.

When I reopen the workbook the pictures are visible again. What causes this issue? How can it be resolved? In options all objects are visible.

[sample of picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmwDu.png)

Comment: Please post your code as properly formatted and indented text, not as a picture.

Comment: @E. Villiger: please find the code above.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Have you tried using `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert` instead, or does that not work for your requirements?

Comment: I've replaced "ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture" by "ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert" and the code still works, thank you. I will continue using the changed document en I hope that the problem won't appear anymore. If it does, I will reopen this thread. Thank you.

Comment: The problem still persists... Also wit pictures that have been inserted with the insert button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code for using Pictures.Insert:

```
With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Filename:=sFileName, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    With .ShapeRange
        .Height = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Height
        .Width = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Width
        .Left = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Left
        .Top = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Top
    End With
End With
```